# Why does all the heat go to the handle of hot pan I cool down with water?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life

I have a hot pan I've just cooked with, and I am holding it on the handle (normally, the handle is only part metal).

If I hold the handle of the pan, near the metal part, as the surface cools from the water I can feel the heat moving from the main surface of the pan, into the handle.

Why does this happen? What is actually happening?

Comment: 1) what does water have to do with the heating of the handle? 2) Doesn't the handle get warmer as you warm the pan, too? I think your perception of the data is flawed/ biased. In other words, you are mis-interpreting the experience.

Comment: @BillN 1) water is how the main surface gets cooled. 2) I've held the metal part of the handle, and hand to drop it because of how much hotter it's gotten after cooling the main surface.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't steam coming off the surface when the water hit the hot pan?  I seriously doubt that the handle suddenly became hot. Heat doesn't flow from hotter to cooler, so if the handle wasn't hot when you picked up the hot pan, it will not get hotter when you cool the pan. BUT, that steam will burn your hand suddenly and you will react by releasing the pan.

Comment: @BillN do you mean heat won't flow from cold to hot?

Comment: Oops! Yes... too late to edit, but "Heat doesn't flow to hotter from cooler ..." Thanks for pointing out the mistake.